# How does one classify aqueous solutions of ions as acidic, basic and neutral?

Tags: acid-base, ions

The following is a homework question:

> Classify the aqueous solutions of the following ions as acidic, basic or neutral:
>           $\ce{C6H5NH3+, Cl- , Fe^3+ , Mg^2+ , HSO4- , NO3- , NH4+ , Al^3+ , C5H5NH+, H2PO4-, CH3CO2-, Cu^2+, Na+, Ag+, ClO4-, PO4^3-, CN-, SH-, Ba^2+}$

I am looking for an approach to solve it.

My thought process so far:

1. If any of the radical is highly reactive with $\ce{H+}$, then the solution will be basic as $\ce{OH-}$ is left. Similarly, if it reacts with $\ce{OH-}$, the solution will be acidic.
2. However, this is where I am confused. Take $\ce{Fe^3+}$ for instance. It is known that it reacts to form $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$, which is a strong base. But, according to my logic above, the solution will be acidic.

Can someone help me with this and possibly give me hints at solving the rest?

Comment: $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ is not a soluble compound. It is actually the hydrate of [iron(iii) oxide hydroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(III)_oxide-hydroxide), which is formed when $\ce{Fe^3+}$ reacts with hydroxide anions. Since it pulls hydroxide out of solution, your intuition is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach thus far is correct. $\ce{Fe^3+}$ *is* acidic; $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ is not a strong base. Indeed, if $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ were a strong base, it would dissociate and form $\ce{Fe^3+}$, but, as you've mentioned, the opposite process happens.

Your confusion may arise from the fact that $\ce{Fe^3+}$ is a Lewis acid, and produces protons in a "different" way than Arrhenius acids:
\begin{align*} \ce{HCl &<=> H+ + Cl-}\\ \ce{Fe^3+ + H2O &<=> Fe(OH)^2+ + H+ }\end{align*}

Either way, your thought process (1.) will work for both cases.

Comment: Will Na+ solution also be acidic then?

Comment: @Tinkidinki, no. $\ce{Na+}$ does not react with $\ce{OH-}$.